# SELinux enforcing blocks network interface

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, selinux, ubuntu-pro

I have installed SELinux on an Ubuntu Pro Server with the following packages:

policycoreutils, selinux-utils, selinux-basics, auditd.

The problem appears when I set SELinux policy to "enforcing". My system loses network capabilities; when I run ifconfig the only interface displayed is the loopback interface.

So I set SELinux back to "permissive" and checked the logs in /var/log/audit/audit.log
I see here that the process systemd-network cannot access the file /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network...
I have tried to perform a system relabel with touch ./autorelabel and a reboot but this does not solve my issue.

Did anyone else experience the same?
How did you overcome it?

Thanks!